# Importing DICOM Files in Python - Missing Attribute

Tags: python, object, attributes, attributeerror

I have a question regarding extracting DVH values from DICOM files in Python.
For that, I followed the basic tutorial for dicompyler:
(https://hub.gke.mybinder.org/user/bastula-dicom-notebooks-ubwtdapd/notebooks/dicompyler-core_usage.ipynb and
https://dicompyler-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html )

```
from dicompylercore import dicomparser, dvh, dvhcalc
dp = dicomparser.DicomParser(r"C:\Users\...\rtss.dcm")

#i.e. Get a dictionary of structure information
structures = dp.GetStructures()

#Access DVH data
rtss = dicomparser.DicomParser(r"C:\Users\...\rtss.dcm")
test = dvh.DVH.from_dicom_dvh(rtss.ds, 5)

test.describe()
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting the error:
**AttributeError: 'FileDataset' object has no attribute 'DVHSequence'**
I guess this example should be pretty straight forward, and I think the issue hass less to do with Dicompyler itself, but more with the format of the file I'm trying to read. (Meaning, I don't quite understand why I'm reading the .dcm file but the dvh module is using .ds?)

I would be very grateful for any input regarding this matter.
Greetings, Tanja

Answer (score 0):

dicompyler-core author here.

You need to use an RT Dose (RTDOSE) DICOM file and not an RT Structure (RTSS) for `from_dicom_dvh`.

`from_dicom_dvh` actually just needs a pydicom `dataset` object. `DicomParser` will internally use pydicom to parse the data, but it also stores a variable to the original pydicom `dataset` object as `ds`. Thus as an alternative, you can read the DICOM file using pydicom and pass it to `from_dicom_dvh`.

Also, there is a [GitHub project](https://github.com/dicompyler/dicompyler-core) if you want a quicker response to issues.